# Android studio - get a translation of an array-string's item in string.xml

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, language-translation, string.xml

I have an application that gives the user the right to choose an item from array in **string.xml**:

```
<array-string name="countries">
    <item>USA</item>
    <item>UK</item>
</array-string>
```

and another array in the **translated-to-Chinese string.xml**:

```
<array-string name="countries">
    <item>美国</item>
    <item>联合王国</item>
</array-string>
```

For example, the app has two `TextViews`, I want the user to select a certain country in Chinese, the first `TextView` shows the value in Chinese & the second shows its value in English (from default string.xml).

I hope my intent is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have various res folders for different locales, you can do something like this:

```
Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("pl");
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Resources resources = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, conf);
String str = resources.getString(id);
```

If your min sdk > 17 try this

```
@NonNull Resources getLocalizedResources(Context context, Locale desiredLocale) {
    Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf = new Configuration(conf);
    conf.setLocale(desiredLocale);
    Context localizedContext = context.createConfigurationContext(conf);
    return localizedContext.getResources();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but my concern is about the single item in an array-string (which is not defined by a "name" or id) & from what I noticed your code is cool if I want to get a normal string resource, could you please edit it for me :)

Comment: Well at that point your lists should be parallel so you can `String[] chineseCountries = getLocalizedResources(context, Locale.CHINA).getStringArray(R.array. countries)` and `String[] englishCountries = getLocalizedResources(context, Locale.US).getStringArray(R.array. countries)` then `chineseCountries[n]` will equal `englishCountries[n]` where n is any int 0 to the size of your list as long as you keep the translations in order

Answer (score 1):

Translated versions of `strings.xml` are not used for this purpose.  
They are used to provide locale-language string resources.  
Since you need in the same language version of your app both the Chinese and the English values you should have put both the string-arrays in the same default `strings.xml` and give them proper ids like `countries_chinese` and `countries_english`.  
Then load them in 2 separate arrays with proper names and use the corresponding values of each.

Comment: Good. That's a way to do it, but for "The corresponding values" how can I get them.
As you know, items in array-string & array don't have name="" property! So should I use an item index in array-string? or put both array-strings in a ArrayList<String>?
what do you think?

Comment: I meant the corresponding indexes of the arrays